# Formatting a JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

So I have the following two sql queries, and I'm trying to build one JSON object for use in my Angular front end.

```
$getCompDetails = mysql_query("SELECT *
            FROM competitions c
            WHERE c.competitionId = '$competitionId'") or die("Couldn't select competition details");

$compDetailsArr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getCompDetails,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    array_push($compDetailsArr,$row);
}

$getCompUsers = mysql_query("SELECT c.userid, u.name, u.profilePic FROM competitionmembers c INNER JOIN users1 u ON  u.id = c.userid WHERE competitionid = '$competitionId'") or die("Couldn't select competitions users");

$compUsersArr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getCompUsers,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    array_push($compUsersArr,$row);
}

$getUsrActs = mysql_query("SELECT activity_typeid, userid, time, activity_weight, activityname
FROM activity_entries
WHERE competitionid = '$competitionId'") or die("Couldn't select activities");

$userActArr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getUsrActs,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    array_push($userActArr,$row);
}

$compDetailsArr["users"] = $compUsersArr;
$compDetailsArr["users"]["activities"] = $userActArr;
echo json_encode($compDetailsArr);
```

This is the result:

```
{
"0": {
    "id": "3371",
    "organisationId": "524bd7c65fd60",
    "competitionId": "52a99783c5d6f",
    "name": "Nordic Challenge",
    "start_date": "2013-12-12",
    "end_date": "2014-05-24",
    "createdby": "531",
    "about": "asdasd",
    "prize": "",
    "prizeImage": "",
    "compCreatedTime": "2013-12-12 11:01:25"
},
"users": {
    "0": {
        "userid": "531",
        "name": "Jane Wilson",
        "profilePic": "A4cMVn-yxQu4fLrpGU7_wwWfbFmAWlt40yS31gv1bTc.png"
    },
    "1": {
        "userid": "1",
        "name": "James Pember",
        "profilePic": "fighter-1.jpg"
    },
    "2": {
        "userid": "1061",
        "name": "Olof Petersson",
        "profilePic": ""
    },
    "3": {
        "userid": "1071",
        "name": "Lars Petersen",
        "profilePic": ""
    },
    "4": {
        "userid": "1081",
        "name": "Mark Johnson",
        "profilePic": ""
    },
    "5": {
        "userid": "971",
        "name": "676",
        "profilePic": "784322701.jpg"
    },
    "activities": [
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "531",
            "time": "2013-12-12 11:01:43",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1061",
            "time": "2013-12-12 11:05:44",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12271",
            "userid": "1071",
            "time": "2013-12-12 11:06:46",
            "activity_weight": "50",
            "activityname": "Deal"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1081",
            "time": "2013-12-12 11:07:45",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "531",
            "time": "2013-12-12 11:10:38",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12271",
            "userid": "531",
            "time": "2013-12-12 16:17:02",
            "activity_weight": "50",
            "activityname": "Deal"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12271",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2013-12-27 10:17:30",
            "activity_weight": "50",
            "activityname": "Deal"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 17:12:30",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:41:03",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12271",
            "userid": "971",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:43:50",
            "activity_weight": "50",
            "activityname": "Deal"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:44:10",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:50:02",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:50:40",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-08 18:58:02",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-09 13:02:25",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "971",
            "time": "2014-01-09 13:03:16",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-10 09:40:59",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-10 09:41:03",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-24 13:00:56",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12261",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-24 13:01:01",
            "activity_weight": "15",
            "activityname": "Conducted"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-24 13:01:27",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-27 13:04:04",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-30 15:23:24",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-30 15:42:37",
            "activity_weight": "10",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-30 19:31:27",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-01-30 19:31:44",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-02-07 14:25:32",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-02-10 12:41:16",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-02-10 12:41:51",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-02-24 15:01:33",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        },
        {
            "activity_typeid": "12251",
            "userid": "1",
            "time": "2014-02-28 07:19:12",
            "activity_weight": "12",
            "activityname": "Booked"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

And this is the desired output format, with each user being a seperate {}'s

```
{
    "organisationId": 1,
    "competitionId": "52eabcf0f3672",
    "currentUser": 2,
    "title": "Sales Hood Q1 Challenge",
    "end_date": "2014-03-01 00:00:00",
    "description": "This is it guys, challenge time!",
    "prizeImage": "placeholder.jpg",
    "prizeDescription": "Dinner for 2!",
    "users": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "John Wilson",
        "profilePic": "fighter-1.jpg",
          "activities" = [{
            "activity_typeid": 312,
            "activityname": Calls
            "activity_weight": 10
          },
          {
            "activity_typeid": 312,
            "activityname": Calls
            "activity_weight": 10
          }]
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Robin Christoper",
        "profilePic": "fighter-3.jpg",
           "activities" = [{
            "activity_typeid": 312,
            "activityname": Calls
            "activity_weight": 10
          }]
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ronald Johnson",
        "profilePic": "placeholder.jpg",
           "activities" = [{
            "activity_typeid": 312,
            "activityname": Calls
            "activity_weight": 10
          }]
    }]
}
```

Would love some help with this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't merge the arrays, instead nest them:

```
$compDetailsArr['users'] = $compUsersArr
$json = json_encode($compDetailsArr);
```

Comment: Hey one quick question, if I wanted to nest one level deeper (activities within users) is it just to use $compDetailsArr["users"]["activities"] = ... ?

Comment: sorry, I can't seem to get that double nest to work - I made an edit - can you check it out?  Thanks again!

Comment: @user2656127 For this kind of task, you'd need to change your SQL and use `JOIN`s.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same case try this:

```
$compDetailsArr = $compDetailsArr;
$compDetailsArr['users'] = array();
$compDetailsArr['users'] = $compUsersArr;
$json = json_encode($compDetailsArr);
```

Comment: so what did you add to the answer of @hjpotter92 other than this: `$compDetailsArr = $compDetailsArr;` which actually does nothing? -1

Comment: @CodeBird I said I have the same case I already used this solution and this is work with me with old and new versions of php, So I answer something I trust and tested.